# Taking h1 heading out of top area and adding to content in Drupal

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

I'd like to move my title from content type "Knowledge base" from it's current spot to my content area - an example:

[image: What I'd like to achieve]

You can see the page itself - [here](http://www.workbooks.com/help/finance/customer_transactions/line_items_help)

I'm using Drupal 7 and have the display suite module installed.

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach I take to this is to move the $title from the page.tpl.php to node.tpl.php

This only works for nodes.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function hook_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['title'] = $variables['node']->type == 'content_type' ? drupal_get_title() : FALSE;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function hook_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $n = menu_get_object();
  if ($n && $n->type == 'content_type') {
    $variables['title'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

You could then use the following in your node.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($title): ?>
  <div class="title">
    <?php print $title; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think there is a contrib module that alters the title field on display suite to allow you to position it etc, but I normally just add these as it feels lighter than adding a full module.

Comment: Won't this affect all my nodes rather than just one content type?

Comment: It would have done, I have just updated this to allow you to do this on a single content type instead.

Comment: Thanks, out of interest where is the reference to content type = knowledge base ?

Comment: In the example, there are two references to 'content_type', that's placeholder text, sorry I should have mentioned, replace this with the machine name of the 'knowledge base' content type.

Comment: No worries, would you be able tot let me know exactly what I need to take out/put in on node.tpl.php and page.tpl.php? I've created a JSFiddle with both my versions in: http://jsfiddle.net/ufjmf35o/

Comment: You can leave page.tpl.php as is, the preprocess_page hook will only hide the title when on a node page of type 'knowledge base'. The preprocess_node hook adds a new variable that is available within the node.tpl.php The second code snippet above should be added to the node template in the place that you want to display the title.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go. So to confirm do I need to delete the current mention of title or will the second snippet (to be placed in the node template) take care of this?

Comment: Inside your node template print:
echo $node->title;
and inside your page page template you should check is current page is node and if it is check it's type and for that specific node type not print page title.